Angular date fields do not get patched
I have a form in my Angular application with three fields: NAME, START DATE, and END DATE. When I attempt to edit the form, the START DATE and END DATE fields are not being patched correctly. It seems like they might not be converting to date objects properly. Below is the relevant code for my component:
@Component({
  selector: 'add-claims-project',
  templateUrl: 'add-claims-project.component.html'
})
export class AddClaimsProjectComponent {
  @Input() claimDetails: any;
  @Input() selectedDataValue: any;
  @Output() closeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public validationService: ValidationService;
  private validationMessages: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } };
  public selectedStartDate: Date;
  public selectedEndDate: Date;

  public claimProjectForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(0),
    projectName: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      NotAllWhitespaceValidator(),
      Validators.maxLength(100),
      Validators.pattern(alphanumericWithSepcialCharactersRegex())
    ], [
      ClaimProjectExistsValidator(this.adminClaimService)
    ]),
    startDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    endDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    claimId: new FormControl('')
  });

  constructor(
    private loadingService: LoadingService,
    private adminClaimService: AdminClaimService,
    private toaster: ToastrService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger
    if (this.claimDetails) {
      this.initialiseValidationService();
      this.claimProjectForm.get('claimId').setValue(this.claimDetails.id);
      this.patchData();
    }
  }

  private patchData(): void {
    if (this.selectedDataValue) {
      debugger
      this.claimProjectForm.patchValue({
        id: this.selectedDataValue.id,
        projectName: this.selectedDataValue.name,
        startDate: this.convertToDateString(this.selectedDataValue.startDate),
        endDate: this.convertToDateString(this.selectedDataValue.endDate)
      });
    }
    this.validationService.setInitalValue();
  }

  private convertToDateString(dateString: string): string {
    console.log('Converting Date String:', dateString);
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
      console.error('Invalid Date:', dateString);
      return '';
    }
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    console.log('Formatted Date:', formattedDate);
    return formattedDate;
  }

  private initialiseValidationService(): void {
    this.validationMessages = {
      projectName: {
        required: 'Project Name is required',
        allWhitespace: 'Project Name cannot be all white spaces',
        maxlength: "Project Name can be max 100 characters",
        pattern: "Project Name should be alphanumeric with special symbols like & - @ ? _ / * , ; : ! ' . only",
        alreadyExists: "Project Name already exists"
      },
      startDate: {
        required: 'Start Date is required',
      },
      endDate: {
        required: 'End Date is required',
      }
    };
    this.validationService = new ValidationService(this.validationMessages, this.claimProjectForm);
    this.validationService.setInitalValue();
  }

  public checkIsFormValid(): boolean {
    return this.claimProjectForm && this.claimProjectForm.valid;
  }

  public save(): void {
    debugger
    this.loadingService.start();
    const payload = this.assignValueToModel();
    const observable = !this.selectedDataValue ?
      this.adminClaimService.addClaimProject(payload) :
      this.adminClaimService.updateClaimProject(payload);

    observable.subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.loadingService.stop();
        if (!this.selectedDataValue) {
          showSuccessMessage("Project Added Successfully", this.toaster);
        } else {
          showSuccessMessage("Project Updated Successfully", this.toaster);
        }
        this.close();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loadingService.stop();
        if (!this.selectedDataValue) {
          showErrorMessage(error, "Error While Adding Project", this.toaster);
        } else {
          showErrorMessage(error, "Error While Updating Project", this.toaster);
        }
        this.close();
      }
    );
  }

  public close(): void {
    this.closeEvent.emit();
  }

  private assignValueToModel(): any {
    return {
      id: this.claimProjectForm.value.id,
      claimId: this.claimDetails.id,
      name: this.claimProjectForm.value.projectName,
      startDate: getMomentDateTimeToSave(this.claimProjectForm.value.startDate),
      endDate: getMomentDateTimeToSave(this.claimProjectForm.value.endDate)
    }
  }

  public onStartDateChange(): void {
    const startDate = this.claimProjectForm.get('startDate').value;
    if (startDate) {
      this.selectedStartDate = new Date(Date.parse(startDate));
      this.claimProjectForm.get('endDate').setValue(null);
    }
  }

  public onEndDateChange(): void {
    const endDate = this.claimProjectForm.get('endDate').value;
    if (endDate) {
      this.selectedEndDate = new Date(Date.parse(endDate));
    }
  }

  public getTitle(): string {
    return this.selectedDataValue ? "Update Project Details" : "Add Project Detail";
  }

Why are the date fields not being patched correctly and how I can fix this issue?"

which format you are getting from API?

It depends on how the component is used. You are performing the patching logic on the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. If the inputs don't have their values at this point in time yet, that would explain the current behavior. Please add a minimal example of the code where the component is used with its data.

A follow-up question would be, does the component need to react to changes of the inputs?

Try patchValue of the actual date, instead of formatting it.
  private patchData(): void {
    if (this.selectedDataValue) {
      debugger
      this.claimProjectForm.patchValue({
        id: this.selectedDataValue.id,
        projectName: this.selectedDataValue.name,
        startDate: this.selectedDataValue.startDate ? new Date(this.selectedDataValue.startDate) : null,
        endDate: this.selectedDataValue.endDate ? new Date(this.selectedDataValue.endDate) : null,
      });
    }
    this.validationService.setInitalValue();
  }

